# How would I nest other controls in my userControl?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

Lets say I have a uc called "zoomBox" that consists of some buttons for functionality and a grid to place the nested content into. How do i make wpf understand that that the grid is where i want the nested tags to be in? By default I just get some error "cannot set name attribute on something that is in scope of another something". To give an example, this is the uc:

```
<UserControl x:Class="zoomBox"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

    <Grid>
        <Grid x:name="this is where nested stuff is supposed to go"/>
        ..some other hypothetical things
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

and this is how i want to use it

```
    <local:zoomBox>
        <StackPanel x:Name="stackPanelThatNeedsZooming!" />
    </local:zoomBox>
```

note: despite using grid, I'm only interested in adding a single child to zoomBox.

Answer (score 3):

> despite using grid, I'm only interested in adding a single child to zoomBox

That's what a [`ContentPresenter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentpresenter.aspx) is for.

And, Since you're already setting the `UserControl`'s [Content](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.content.aspx) in the very same XAML that declares the UserControl, by doing:

```
<UserControl...>
    <SomeContent/>
</UserControl>
```

You can't define the content twice. That's why you're getting errors.

Instead of that, you will have to [Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295273.aspx) the control so that it supports having a predefined content and a "placeholder" where new content will be placed:

```
<UserControl x:Class="YourNamespace.zoomBox"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourNamespace"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <UserControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:zoomBox}">
            <Grid>
               <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Content" 
                                 x:Name="This is where your nested content will go"/>
              ..some other hypothetical things
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </UserControl.Template>
</UserControl>
```

Notice that I added an extra `xmlns` that maps to the CLR namespace where the `zoomBox` class is defined in order to be able to define the `TargetType` of the `ControlTemplate`.

For further details, please refer to [MSDN: WPF Content Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613548%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

BTW, please use proper naming conventions, it should be `ZoomBox` with an uppercase "Z".

Comment: I know this is over a year old... I just tried your XAML snippet above and doesn't compile. I get a compilation error on the top <UserControl> tag saying "'zoomBox' ControlTemplate TargetType does not match templated type 'UserControl'. If I replace {x:Type local:zoomBox}" with {x:Type UserControl}" then it compiles but the content doesn't appear. Any ideas on this?  Thanks